# Multer delete previous image when new upload image size is larger than given limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

Why multer delete previous image when the new uploading image size exceeds file size limit?

Code is give below:

```
var connection = require('../config');
const express = require('express');
const requireAuth = require('../middleware/jwt_verify')
const multer = require('multer');
const router = express.Router(); 

const fileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
    if(file.mimetype === "image/jpg"  || file.mimetype ==="image/jpeg"  || file.mimetype ===  
"image/png") {
        callback(null, true);
    } else {
        callback(new Error("Upload only Image of type jpg/jpeg or png"),false);
    }
}

var uploadImage = multer ({
    storage: multer.diskStorage ({
        destination: function (req, file, callback) 
        { 
            callback(null, './uploads/images')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, callback) 
        { 
            callback(null, file.originalname + ".jpg")
        }
    }),
    fileFilter: fileFilter,
    limits: { fileSize: 1000},
})
.single('image');

router.post('/uploadImage',requireAuth, uploadImage, (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        status:true,
        message:"Successfully uploaded!",
    })
}, (error, req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
        status:false,
        message:error.message,
    })
})

module.exports = router;
```

Its is working for uploading images but when the given limit exceeds it deleted the previous image of that user.

Thanks

Comment: same issue. any solution for this.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66843068/multer-deletes-uploaded-image-if-new-uploaded-image-hits-a-limit-file-to-large